# Rotating vector based upon area

Tags: python

I have a normal vector like
normal=Vector((0.0, 0.0, 1.0))
that I want to rotate 90° in the x-y plane and wonder how to do this?

/Max

Comment: One thing, I will not use the rotated vector, only print it to a textfile.

Comment: Are you asking specifically how to do this using Python in Blender, or is it the math behind it you need help with?